# How to get data from Table which has errors after dropping of schema?

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltype

I have problem to get data from table which became invalid after schema deletion by calling:

```
DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.DELETESCHEMA()
```

When I want to select data from table by:

```
SELECT * FROM errortable;
```

this error occurs:

> 4063. 00000 -  "%s has errors"
>         *Cause:    Attempt to execute a stored procedure or use a view that has
>                errors.  For stored procedures, the problem could be syntax errors
>                or references to other, non-existent procedures.  For views,
>                the problem could be a reference in the view's defining query to
>                a non-existent table.
>                Can also be a table which has references to non-existent or
>                inaccessible types.
>         *Action:   Fix the errors and/or create referenced objects as necessary.

After selecting:

```
select * from user_objects where status = 'INVALID';
```

I can see "errortable" in invalid objects?

Could anybody help me how to fix the table (How to fix the errors and/or create referenced objects as necessary.) or how to export the table data?

Thank you

Comment: Did you take a backup prior to dropping the schema?

Comment: I did backup query: select * from oldtable into errortable; Then dropped oldtable but now unable to read data from errortable after deleting the schema.

Comment: Does the `user_errors` view give you more information? What is the definition of `errortable` - can you get its DDL from `dbms_metadata` calls? What happens if you re-register the schema - or don't you have the definition of the one you deleted?

Comment: In user_errors is nothing special regarding my error, I am not allowed to use dbms_metadata. I tried to re-register the schema and it didn't help to errortable. I am using Oracle 11 database version.